# QGraphicsScene too wide

Tags: qt, qlayout

I've got a problem with my layout and I can't find any solution. Below are two images. The first one is from the Qt Designer, where everything looks great (but there is no QGraphicsScene, so it's expectable). The second one is real app, where the left bottom scene is too wide. As scene rect I'm taking `this->ui->juliaMandelbrot->geometry()`, which means geometry of the QGraphicsView. But this returns 640x150 instead of 225x150. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

[image: Qt Designer]
[image: Real application]

Answer (score 0):

although I don't like it, I set maximum width of graphics view and it solved my problem.

I don't like it, because the grandparent of my graphics view has already set maximum width, so I thought, that children inherit this property :-(.